# How can I get the values in this json

Tags: json

I'm trying to select avg in this JSON, but I can not get it to work. My option in this moment is `data.user_stats.items[0]['avg']` and i'm trying to do it with this: `data.user_stats.items[0].['avg']`

```
"data": {
    "user": {
        "id": "2",
        "code": "user2",
    },
    "user_stats": {
        "items": {
            "ITEM-01-Alumno": {
                "sum": 0,
                "qty": 6,
                "avg": 0,
                "exercises": {
                    "ITEM-1": "0.00"
                }
            },
            "ITEM-02-Alumno": {
                "sum": 10,
                "qty": 1,
                "avg": 10,
                "exercises": {
                    "ITEM-2": 10
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `items` is not an array, it is an object. You'd have to select it via:

```
data.user_stats.items['ITEM-01-Alumno'].avg
```

Of course, you could change it into an array, but you'll lose the labeling. Unless you move the name into the object data:

```
"data": {
    "user": {
        "id": "2",
        "code": "user2",
    },
    "user_stats": {
        "items": [
            {
                "label": "ITEM-01-Alumno",
                "sum": 0,
                "qty": 6,
                "avg": 0,
                "exercises": {
                    "ITEM-1": "0.00"
                }
            },
            {
                "label": "ITEM-02-Alumno",
                "sum": 10,
                "qty": 1,
                "avg": 10,
                "exercises": {
                    "ITEM-2": 10
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You might also want to look at the `exercises` section, it might also benefit from a restructure unless you want to do a `for...in` loop or `Object.keys` later.

Comment: but Imagine that you don´t know label [ITEM-01-Alumno].it´s 
possible select the avg in iterator or something similar.

Comment: @N3kO_206 True, but if you don't need a map, then changing to an array will net you a performance gain since iterating and access in an array is faster.